# Want to examine results of python regex match (groups) inside conditional

Tags: python, regex

I am wanting to check if one of a number of regex matches succeeds.  If it does, I want access to the groups in the match.  If I didn't need the groups, I could do something like this:

```
if re.match(pobj1,string):
    # First match worked
elif re.match(pobj2,string):
    # First match failed, but second one worked.
[...]
```

Since I haven't assigned the result of the match to anything, I don't see how to access any of the groups that were part of the match.  So instead I'm assigning the matches to a variable before the conditional.  But that means I'm running all the matches every time, not just the necessary ones.

```
mobj1 = re.match(pobj1,string)
mobj2 = re.match(pobj2,string)  # Might be expensive
if mobj1:
    # First match succeeded.  Use the match information
    primary_list.append(mobj1.group(1))
elif mobj2:
    # First match failed, but second one worked.  Use info from #2.
    secondary_list.append(mobj2.group(1))
[...]
```

How do I only run the matches that are necessary, while still being able to access the groups from that match at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

I would list up your objects and run through them with a loop and breaking it once you found a match.

```
for o in list_of_objects:
    matches = re.match(o,string)
    if matches:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list of patterns and find the first matching one with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

```
>>> import re
>>> patterns = [re.compile('a.c'), re.compile('1.3'), re.compile('4.6')]
>>> next((p for p in patterns if p.match('abc')), None)
re.compile('a.c')
>>> next((p for p in patterns if p.match('436')), None)
re.compile('4.6')
>>> next((p for p in patterns if p.match('XYZ')), None)
```

`None` as a second argument for `next` is used to avoid a StopIteration:

```
>>> next(p for p in patterns if p.match('XYZ'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```